# F# function return value

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

I'm new to F# and when I was trying to implement function `rpt` I found some troubles.

```
let rec rpt f n x =
    if n=0 then x
    else 
       f ( rpt f (n-1) x )
```

When I have called this function as `rpt (fun x -> x*x) 4 2`. Answer was ok `val it : int = 65536` But when I change `rpt` as follows (only multiplying by 2) :

```
let rec rpt f n x =
    if n=0 then 2*x
    else 
       f ( rpt f (n-1) x )
```

Function returns only zero : `val it : int = 0`. Can anyone explain what happens?

Comment: Is the `int` return value overflowing? Does it work for other inputs?

Comment: @Lee Yes, you are totally right, thanks. I was so confused about understanding functional paradigm so that I haven't seen that obvious reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeating a squaring function four times gives a total power of 2^4 = 16, which perfectly aligns with your first answer - 65536 = 2^16. But if you add an additional second power at the beginning, you get the total power of 16*2 = 32, which happens to be exactly the size of the `int` type, so it overflows perfectly and gives zero.

You can verify this by replacing `int` with `int64`:

```
let rec rpt f n x =
    if n=0 then 2L*x
    else 
       f ( rpt f (n-1) x )

> rpt (fun x -> x*x) 4 2L;;
val it : int64 = 4294967296L

> pown 2L 32;;
val it : int64 = 4294967296L
```